# How to setup Nlog and Autofac .Net Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, nlog

I have a solution with a structure of projects like this. It's a .Net Core app with Razor Pages used on the front.

```
Frontend
|
|
BusinessLogic
|
|
DataAccess
```

I am aiming to user NLog as a logger. And I am failing AF.
I used this snippet in the Fronted project:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
            {
                webHostBuilder
                  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                  .UseIISIntegration()
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                  {
                      logging.ClearProviders();
                      logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                  })
                .UseNLog();

            })
            .Build();
```

But services located in the Business logic require injection of the Nlog ILogger. And I keep on getting exception

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with >'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type >'BusinessLogic.Services.ApplicationService' can be invoked with the available >services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'AutoFac.Extras.NLog.DotNetCore.ILogger logger'

As you can see I tried using the AutoFac.Extras.NLog.DotNetCore but it didn't help. I am really confused how to setup Nlog properly with a .net core app.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder
              .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .UseIISIntegration()
              .UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog()
        .Build();
```